# Inter thread data transfer - Linux

Tags: pthreads, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

My program have two thread created from main thread. Each thread operates on seperate external communicating device connected.

```
                main thread
    thread_1                        thread_2
```

Thread_1 receives data packet from external device. Each data packet is an structure of 20 bytes each.

Now i want thread_2 to read data received by thread_1 & transfer it to device connected to it.

How can we transfer data between my two threads.

What exact name of the linux variables types to use in this case ?

Comment: use share memory with mutex control.

Comment: @tAmirNaghizadeh no need for shared memory as both threads are in the same process.

Comment: @Marko Some Global Variable could be shared,though they shared memory!,the problem is how to interact and when to used the result values. On solution is using async I/O over some form of communication like: socket,Zeromq. Zeromq make inner thread communication possible. [zmq-inproc](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2:zmq-inproc)

Comment: Do you using kernel-space threads?,since working over device drivers.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is a classic example of the [Producer Consumer Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).

There a number of possible ways to implement this depending on the context - your post is tagged with both `pthreads`, and `linux-device-drivers`.  Is this kernel-space, user-space, or kernel-space -> userspace?

### Kernel Space

A solution is likely to involve a ring buffer (if you anticipate that multiple messages between threads can be in flight at once) and a semaphore.

Chapter 5 of [Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch05.pdf) would be a good place to start.

### User-space

If both threads are in user-space,  the producer-consumer pattern in the same process is usually implemented with a `pthread` [condition variable](http://ok.com/MONITOR/CV.html). An worked example of how to do it is [here](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~niehaus/classes/678-s11/labs/pthreads_pc/pthreads_pc_lab.pdf)

### Kernel-space -> User-space

The general approach used in Linux is for user-space thread `thread_2` to block on a filing system object signalled by kernel-space `thread_1`.  Typically the filing system object in question is in `/dev` or `/sys`.    LDD3 has examples of both approaches.

Comment: `kernel-space->User-space`: Would it be possible for a kernel modules ,which working on kernel memory, using threads in a user-land memory ?,two separate process using the same thread?

Comment: If what you are asking is whether you can have several user-space threads accessing a single queue operating in kernel space - yes.

Comment: what do you mean by `kernel-space->User-space` , two thread on different space?